# jQuery Not Responding to Second 'this'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've written this function to switch between font awesome arrows:

```
function toggleClass() {
    $('.fa-arrow-up').on('click', function (event) {
        $('.info-section').toggleClass('hidden');
        $(this).addClass('fa-arrow-down').removeClass('fa-arrow-up')
        // console.log($(this))
    })

    $('.fa-arrow-down').on('click', function (event) {
        $('.info-section').toggleClass('hidden');
        $(this).addClass('fa-arrow-up').removeClass('fa-arrow-down')
        console.log($(this))
    })
}
$(toggleClass);
```

On the first click when the class is `fa-arrow-up` it works, when the class is `fa-arrow-down` and I click it for a second time, it is toggling the `.info-section`, but not replacing the `fa-arrow-down` with `fa-arrow-up`. Any suggestions on why this function is not working both ways?

UPDATE adding HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <i class="fas fa-arrow-up" aria-hidden="false"></i>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
        integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/c79911a95b.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Give us your HMTL as well, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this help you.

```js
$('.fa-arrow-up').on('click', function(event) {
  $(this).toggleClass('fa-arrow-down fa-arrow-up')
})
```

```html
<i class="fas fa-arrow-up" aria-hidden="false"></i>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/c79911a95b.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for the issue.

HTML

```
<button class="arrow-icon" type="button">
    <i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i>
</button>
```

CSS

```
.arrow-icon .fa-arrow-up{
    display: inline-block;
}
.arrow-icon .fa-arrow-down{
    display: none;
}
.arrow-icon.active-icon .fa-arrow-up{
    display: none;
}
.arrow-icon.active-icon .fa-arrow-down{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

JS

```
$(function(){
    $('.arrow-icon').on('click', function(){
        $('.info-section').toggleClass('hidden');
        $(this).toggleClass('active-icon');
    });
});
```